# Какой системе нужно меньше ресурсов?

Tags: unix

Здравствуйте!

Какой системе нужно меньше ресурсов? Lubuntu или Xubuntu.Ставиться на ноутбук. За какой комфортней работать?Мне по скринам нравиться Xubuntu.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ребят, очень срочно нужно.

Comment: По опыту Lubuntu требует меньше ресурсов и более шустрая. Но Xubuntu намного удобнее.Напишите кто нибудь точный ответ и я выберу его правильным.

Comment: Закройте вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ищите минималистичный дистрибутив что ли? Загляните тогда сюда, например: http://distrowatch.com/index.php?language=RU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну до кучи еще и mint попробуйте. А вообще, скорее всего у вас браузер самое прожерливое звено, особенно если он называется Firefox и особенно если включен flash... Chromium-browser или Opera будут легче. Кстати, Debian на десктопах не лучший выбор, я его только на серверах использую, там ему как раз самое место. Все остальные распространенные дистры примерно одинаковы, отличие в рабочих столах. Можно ставить любую хоть Lubuntu хоть Xubuntu, а затем доустановить дополнительный рабочий стол XFCE или LXDE соответственно, про openbox заодно вспомните. Но, если у вас таки есть горячее желание поглубже залезть в оптимизацию системы под железо, тогда однозначно Gentoo :)

Comment: Мне нужно что бы работало. Поставил Xubuntu - работает хорошо, при запуске проц грузит на 100% а потом обратно на 3-5%. оперативки хватает. QT вообще прекрасно работает.

Comment: Понимаете, вот ведь какая штука - ваши проц, память и прочее грузят какие-то определенные процессы (не сама система), я вам о том и толкую. Узнайте их поименно, тогда будет легче выяснить, что именно следует оптимизировать. Вот три варианта:<br />— консольная утилита "top" (должна быть в вашей системе)— консольная утилита "htop" (устанавливается "sudo apt-get install htop")— графическая, прожорливая программа "gnome-system-monitor" (устанавливается дополнительно)Воспользуйтесь чем либо подобным и последите, что является главным тормозом системы. А свои догадки я вам донес выше.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен, Debian + LXDE "Жестковато" конечно но для старого железа то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Какое железо то? Может оно и убунту с юнити вытянет. Я вчера запускал на PIII 933 512 - работало... Думаю на ноутбук даже 6-ти летней давности можно смело ставить всё из перечисленного и гораздо больше...

Comment: Убунту не потянул. Я поставил xubuntu, работает хорошо, но при более 2 процессах( браузер+ Qt) начинает подтормаживать. Lubuntu мне внешне не нравиться.Железо: fujitsu siemens lifebook s7020D@salt, Есть какие то советы?

Comment: Не знаю, может памяти добавить...

Comment: @salt, я спрашивал не про апргрейд, а о ОС. Оперативки хватает, а вот проц часть на 100% загружен.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать ещё [DSL - Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), который умеет работать даже на 486DX с 16 мегабайтами оперативы. (Если вы вообще такое помните...)

Comment: Конечно помню :), я ещё не родился когда это было.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит попробовать Linux Mint Debian c Cinnamon.По моему среда Cinnamon более удобна нежели Mate.

Answer (score 1):

Могу добавить, что у меня RussianFedoraRemix 16.1 прекрасно "ездит" на IBM ThinkPad 600x (PIII-500MHz, 576 MB, 40GB) под LXDE или openbox.
Главное - отключил ресурсы, редко используемые, но при этом автоматически загружающиеся. FireFox, конечно, конкретно поджирает ресурсы, но и на такой машине работает.
С печатью больших файлов - облом, банально не хватает ресурсов. В остальном, сыну для подготовки уроков хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще считается что xubuntu для самых слабых машин, а вообще ставь ubuntu server без графического сервера + mc.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu должна меньше требовать чем xUbuntu. Да и на счет удобности кому как. + все эти DE настраиваемы, вы можете настроить некоторые детали которые будут из lubuntu похожи на xubuntu и наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо. Я выбрал xubuntu - lubuntu совсем уж некрасивая.

Answer (score 1):

посоветую вот такую ОС http://crunchbang.org/  у меня на нетбуке просто самолет

Answer (score 1):

выключенной системе вообще не надо ни ресурсов, ни электропитания и не шумит :)по делу - любой изеначально консольный вариант линукса + xfce4/e17(18)

Answer (score 1):

у меня Xubuntu 12.04 стоит с момента релиза и с тех пор проблем никаких небыло... в ней еще есть фишка что можно отключить всякие ненужные эффекты прозрачности там тени окон